# Is there anywhere I can find an example of a complex JSON schema?

Tags: json, schema

I am trying to learn JSON so that I can develop a proper schema for my dataset. I am comfortable with the syntax of the language but there are some intricacies within my dataset that leave me unsure as to how to best proceed.

I typically learn best by looking at examples and then trying to relate them to my data. Unfortunately, all of the JSON examples I have found are very simple and don't seem to cover more advanced use cases. Can anyone point me to a relatively complex schema so that I can take a look at it and see if it is able to elucidate some of the finer points of JSON? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean JSON structures examples or http://json-schema.org/?

Comment: http://json-schema.org/example2.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble while building a schema validator; there aren't many complex example schemata out there.

The most complex schema I found was the [JSON Metaschema](http://json-schema.org/schema) (the schema used to validate schemata). This is both a complex schema in itself, and describes what is possible with JSON schemata.

I hope that helps.